# Random order on {block:Posts} on Tumblr

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I have a problem in a customized tumblr theme.

It's a photo gallery and i need to randomize the order of the posts on the homepage, to look different on each page refresh. I tried with some trick to disorder the divs of each photos, but, the theme have pagination, so, the disorder is only on the actual page that you are, not with all the posts.

So, i need a trick in the declaration

```
{block:Posts}
// code of the posts
{/block:Posts}
```

I need a shuffle order on the posts and no the classic DATE DESC order. Anybody had the same problem? Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't possible. Posts will always be in reverse chronological order: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: :( let me continue trying with the javascript to disorder ths divs. thanks friend.